# scope of non-member, non static variables and methods

Tags: c++, scope

**Test.h**

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    //some methods
private:
    int var;
    //some vars
}
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "Test.h"
int a;

void func()
{
     //some code here
}
Test::Test()
{
     //some code
}
```

Variable `a` and function `func()` are non-member and non-static.

What is the lifetime of variable `a` and function `func()`?

Consider Test class as a part of a shared library. Can other classes of that library access `a` or `func()` by resolution operator ?

What is difference between static declaration of variable `a`/ `func()` and nonstatic declaration of `a`/`func()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7kfh662%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) page is the answer to your question. It defines scope and Lifetime.

`a` have scope and life time through out the file since its global.

`func()` doesnt have scope or lifetime. they only have visibility.

if its part of shared library also functions and global variables can be accessed by other parts provided library is visible.

In this case being static doesnt make much of a difference. But local variables when made static gets global scope but will have only local visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Variables and functions have the same scope: they exist from their point of declaration onward.

This is relatively different from attributes and methods of a class whose scope is limited to the class itself and where order matters less (though it may... for types).

Answer (score 1):

Variable `a` is a global variable, its scope is entire program runtime i.e its created during your program startup and destroyed during program exit. `func` is a global function and functions do not have any concept of scope attached to them.

Comment: You're talking about the object lifetime. The lexical scope of each name is from the point of declaration until the end of the translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

Variable "a" is a global variable to Test.cpp
and "func" is a normal function in Test.cpp.
***Edit section:-***
But u can use the same variable & method in different place if u do the same as listed below.

```
//file1.h
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H
extern int a;
extern void func();
#endif    
//end of file1.h

//file1.cpp
#include"file1.h"    
int a; // a=0 as it is global variable
static int x = 10;// Scope is limited, it can only be used in file1.cpp

static void func2(){ 
    int z = x;
    z = x+z;
    //... some thing u r doing    
} 
void func(){
    //... some thing u r doing    
}      
//end of file1.cpp


//file2.cpp
#include"file1.h"
//U can use variable "a" & method "func" defined in file1.cpp . For an eg:-    
int add(int b){
    func();//func defined in file1.cpp but used here
    //func2(); //It will throw error if you remove the comment before func2 method as 
               //the scope of func2 is limited to file1.cpp as it is static method
    return a+b;// a defined in file1.cpp but used here
}    
int main(){    
    //some code exists here
    return 0;
}

//end of file2.cpp
//================
```

There are lot of things by which u can play around. It just one of the example.
Like if you declare static global variable then scope of that variable is limited to that file only.

Variable "a" & "func" is accessible by other classes present in the same file where the Test Class is present.

If you declare any variable or method as static global variable then the scope of that variable & method is limited to that file as explained in above example.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ a **scope**, defined by C++11 §3.3.1/1, is a (possibly discontiguous) *region of text* where a name can be used unqualified to refer to the same entity.

A **potential scope** is the scope a name will have when there are no declarations of the same name within the potential scope.

The scope of your variable name and function name extends from the declaration, to the end of the file.